# Sql Server Reporting Server connect SQL Server with encrypted connection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I use sql server reporting server to host my msreporting.I want to encrypt my sql server connection encrypted on network

Normally I can add encrypt=true value to mysqlserver connection string and that time it works in my c# code.How can do same feature in sql server reporting server(SSRS 2019)

c# sample
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data source=HOSTNAME;Initial catalog=databaseName;User Id=userName;Password=password;encrypt=true